# Removing dates when there is a year gap between data in excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am trying to create a share price graph with historical share price and future estimate price in one year time.
When i plot the graph I am using the historical prices for the year , which is not an issue. 
I later add one share price number with a date that is 1 year from the last historical price. Excel automatically populates the gap in dates but in the process scales the graph to the newly populated dates.

Please see below historical price before 1 year price is added:
[image]

Please see below the future price added to historical price (scatter plot graph):
[image]

Is there a way to remove the date gap as to show the end date of historical price and the future date? Or at least remove automatic scaling?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of, neither of them particularly elegant.

1. Make a text column to show your dates - you can use the `TEXT` formula to set the format that you want. Then insert a line chart to plot your data, using the text column as the x-axis. You can set any spacing that you like then. The downside is that if any of your data is irregularly-spaced, your scale will be distorted.
2. Make two plots and put them side by side, removing the right-hand axis from the left one and the left-hand axis from the right one. You have to remember to set the vertical scales to be the same.

Comment: good tips, I started to type exactly the same two! Just one comment for line chart: you can specify for the axis that you want a text axis, so it isn't necessary to convert dates to text before.